# Assume that A and B are square matrices, so that $AB = B^2A$. Prove $(AB)^2=B^6A^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have no idea how to solve this or if I miss any properties,I will appreciate any kind of help and explanation.
Excuse me for my broken english, is not my first language

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that : $ AB = B^2A$, so:

$(AB)^2 = (AB)(AB) = (B^2A)(B^2A) = B^2(AB)(BA) = B^2 (B^2A)(BA) = B^4(AB)A = B^4(B^2A)A = B^6A^2 $

Answer (score 1):

$(AB)^2=(B^2A)^2=B^2AB^2A=B^2(AB)BA=B^2(B^2A)BA=(B^2B^2)(AB)A=B^4(B^2A)A=(B^4B^2)(AA)=B^6A^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$(AB)^2=(B^2A)(B^2A)=B^2 (AB)BA=B^2B^2(AB)A=B^2B^2B^2AA$$

Comment: That's a *hint*?